# Wordpress/ACF merging multiple fields value to one

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

Is there any way to get values from multiple fields (for example: *“value_1”*, *“value_2”*, etc.) and merge all of them to a new field, let`s say *“merged_values”* after publishing/editing the post?

Something like this:

If:

```
value_1 = red blue; value_2 = gold silver;
```

Then:

```
merged_values = red blue gold silver;
```

I need to achieve this, because of a search plugin, that doesn`t show the results if the search query is *“red silver”* and there is no option in it to combine the search within multiple ACF fields.

(to be exact, I need the *“merged_values”* field to be written in the db as the example above – not just echo the values together in the front-end).

The output from the default fields is pure text with spaces and the *"merged_values"* should also be just pure text (no arrays, etc.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you want something like this

```
// This function runs after your post is saved
function my_acf_save_post( $post_id ) {

    // Get new value of field 1
    $value1 = get_field( 'field1', $post_id );

    // Get new value of field 2 
    $value2 = get_field( 'field2', $post_id );

    // Merged values with ; on the end
    $merge = implode(" ",$value1).' '.implode(" ",$value2);

    // Update field 3 with the new value which should be
    // value1 value2;
    update_field( 'field3', $merge, $post_id );
}
add_action('acf/save_post', 'my_acf_save_post', 20);
```

I'm not sure if you wanted to put the merged value in another ACF field. If not you can use $wpdb to insert it in de database manually.

Comment: This returns "Array Array;" to the final field. (And also, no need to remove ";", that`s not in the content of the fields (just used it to separate it here)).

Comment: Sorry, my bad - the main fields were checkboxes - I used implode - answer at the bottom :) THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Comment: I changed this answer. Can you mark this one as the answer and remove your own answer. Otherwise it will confuse people who might have the same question.

Comment: Done. Just the "// Merged values with ; on the end" isn`t right, cause there`s no ; there :)

Comment: @MartinPetro is this still working? I am trying to achieve something like this: merge 2 fields (field1 value uses labels as selectbox and other field2 is time as string) is there any solution, I am lost now...

Comment: @zte813 Hey, it should, but it depends on what the $value is - in my scenario it was a string, but in your`s it could be an array with label, value etc. You can try to add $value1 = $value1['value'] under the first declaration of the variable from original post.