# Merge ACF fields into another ACF field

Tags: wordpress, concatenation, advanced-custom-fields

I'm building an athlete profile database using ACF (Advanced Custom Fields). I have fields for First Name, Last Name, and Full Name. Athletes will be able to enter their first and last names on the front end of the website when they are creating a profile. I don't want them to enter their full name also because that's a bad user experience. But I need the full name on the backend. Is there a way to have the Full Name text field auto-generated by merging the values of First Name and Last Name? I don't want to enter the full name manually. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

with this kind of thing you are wanting to combine 2 fields into 1 record it may just be easier to ask for the full name in 1 field this is not a bad user experience as much as you may think more people actually find it more annoying needing to put different parts of there name in different boxes.

However if this is what you are wanting to move forward with I did find this which may be of some assistance [Wordpress/ACF merging multiple fields value to one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53300685/wordpress-acf-merging-multiple-fields-value-to-one/)

Comment: Thank you. I'll check it out. The main reason I want separate fields is that I need to be able to sort by first or last name.