# Sanitize and combine four ACF fields into one new ACF field

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm combining four individual ACF fields into one text field, but I need to sanitize those entries individually so I can use them all as CSS classes. I've been trying to use sanitize_title() to turn  plain english field values into the equivalent of post slugs—lowercase with dashes instead of spaces and no special characters.

A simplified, two-field example would be:

`Status One / Status Two` and `Sector One / Sector Two / Sector Three`

into

`status-one-status-two sector-one-sector-two-sector-three`

Note that I'm trying to sanitize before merging so I can keep my entries separated by spaces (i.e. multiple CSS classes instead of one-incredibly-long-css-class.

I found the original function [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53302051/16761523) and successfully modified it to merge four of my fields into a fifth ACF field.

```
function my_acf_save_post( $post_id ) {

    $value1 = get_field( 'status', $post_id );
    $value2 = get_field( 'sector', $post_id );
    $value3 = get_field( 'subsector', $post_id );
    $value4 = get_field( 'lead', $post_id );

    $clean1 = sanitize_title( $value1 );
    $clean2 = sanitize_title( $value2 );
    $clean3 = sanitize_title( $value3 );
    $clean4 = sanitize_title( $value4 );

    $merge = implode(" ",$clean1).' '.implode(" ",$clean2).' '.implode(" ",$clean3).' '.implode(" ",$clean4);

    update_field( 'css_classes', $merge );
}
add_action('acf/save_post', 'my_acf_save_post', 20);
```

I've tried a number of `sanitize_*` functions—most of them at this point—and a kajillion different syntaxes and I still can't get it to work because I'm a designer who writes a bit of code and not a developer (but you know that by now). kthxbai in advance.

Comment: Why do you need this fifth field in the first place? Do you want people to be able to edit it? Even if you did, this code would erase it and reset it each time. I think you can get rid of the fifth field and just echo the four fields out as you see fit.

Comment: I'm using the data from the four (user-editable) fields to display information in plain english on the frontend of the site. I'm using the fifth field to concatenate and sanitize the data so I can repurpose it for a script I've written to filter by those same variables. When a user updates one/any of the four fields, I want it to push that change to the CSS classes and update the filters on the front end. So far, everything's working but the sanitizing, and I can't use spaces and slashes in CSS classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out this code to create a slug and merge fields into one.

```
function custom_slug($text, string $divider = '-')
{
    // replace non letter or digits by divider
    $text = preg_replace('~[^\pL\d]+~u', $divider, $text);

    // transliterate
    $text = iconv('utf-8', 'us-ascii//TRANSLIT', $text);

    // remove unwanted characters
    $text = preg_replace('~[^-\w]+~', '', $text);

    // trim
    $text = trim($text, $divider);

    // remove duplicate divider
    $text = preg_replace('~-+~', $divider, $text);

    // lowercase
    $text = strtolower($text);

    if (empty($text)) {
        return 'n-a';
    }

    return $text;
}



function my_acf_save_post( $post_id ) {

    $value1 = get_field( 'status', $post_id );
    $value2 = get_field( 'sector', $post_id );
    $value3 = get_field( 'subsector', $post_id );
    $value4 = get_field( 'lead', $post_id );

    $clean1 = custom_slug( $value1 );
    $clean2 = custom_slug( $value2 );
    $clean3 = custom_slug( $value3 );
    $clean4 = custom_slug( $value4 );

    $merge = $clean1.' '.$clean2.' '.$clean3.' '.$clean4;

    update_field( 'css_classes', $merge, $post_id );
}
add_action('acf/save_post', 'my_acf_save_post', 20);
```

Comment: Thank you, @zillionera_dev — this project took a turn in a different direction soon after I posted this question, but I really appreciate your help.